# InvalidOperationException for Speech Recognition Grammar

Tags: c#, speech-recognition, grammar

I am trying to write a program that generates speech recognition grammar from a file and stores the phrases in a dictionary where the keys are the phrases. The following code:

```cs
sre.LoadGrammarAsync(new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder(new Choices(commands.Keys.ToArray()))));
```

Throws this exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The language for the grammar does not match the language of the speech recognizer.
   vid System.Speech.Recognition.RecognizerBase.ThrowIfSapiErrorCode(SAPIErrorCodes errorCode)
   vid System.Speech.Recognition.RecognizerBase.LoadSapiGrammarFromCfg(SapiGrammar sapiGrammar, Grammar grammar, Uri baseUri, Boolean enabled, Single weight, Int32 priority)
   vid System.Speech.Recognition.RecognizerBase.LoadSapiGrammar(Grammar grammar, SapiGrammar sapiGrammar, Boolean enabled, Single weight, Int32 priority)
   vid System.Speech.Recognition.RecognizerBase.LoadGrammarAsyncCallback(Object grammarObject)
```

And I have no idea of why this is happening, because all generated phrases are in English, and the program specifically demands the `SpeechRecognitionEngine` to use a `RecognizerInfo` with a culture of *en-US* (or `Culture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName` of `"en"`).

I have `MS-1033-80-DESK (en-US)` `Microsoft Speech Recognizer 8.0 for Windows (English - US)` installed.

Answer (score 0):

I simply had to specify the *Culture* of my grammar. Here's the working code:

```cs
sre.LoadGrammarAsync(new Grammar(
    new GrammarBuilder(new Choices(commands.Keys.ToArray())) {
        Culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(Settings.CompatibleCultureInfo)
    }
));
```